# jquery keyup function for form validation

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to embed keyup function into this code I am currently have. The code is working fine however I have to click outside of the input field to get it executed.

I believe on keyup function will eliminate that behavior and make it more live. But I am a beginner in jquery and java script, so your help will be much appreciated ...

```
$(document).ready(function (){
validate();
$('#FirstName, #LastName, #PhoneNumber, #Email, #Age, #Profession, #ChooseYourCoursePreferableMonth, #AreYouBringingYourLaptop, #hear, #PreferableContactMethod').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
if (
    $('#FirstName').val().length   >   2   &&
    $('#LastName').val().length  >   2   &&
    $('#PhoneNumber').val().length    >   7   &&
    $('#Email').val().length    >   0   &&
    $('#Age').val().length    >   0   &&
    $('#Profession').val().length    >   0   &&
    $('#ChooseYourCoursePreferableMonth').val().length    >   0   &&
    $("input[name='AreYouBringingYourLaptop']:checked").val().length    >   0   &&
    $('#hear').val().length    >   0   &&
    $("input[name='PreferableContactMethod']:checked").val().length    >   0
    )

{   // FILLED
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    $('input[type=submit]').val('Submit Form');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('color', '#383838');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('background-color', '#63bc46');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('font-size','18px');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('cursor','pointer');

}else {
    // NOT FILLED
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    $('input[type=submit]').val('Fill in all required fields to Submit Form');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('color', '#a0a0a0');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('background-color', '#f3f3f3');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('font-size','15px');
    $('input[type=submit]').css('cursor','auto');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `.keyup()`. I will post an example.

```
$( "input[type=submit]" ).keyup(function() {
   validate();
});
```

Example on jQuery website: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 0):

Use .on("input")

This will call the function every time you press a key inside a certain input

Like this:

```
$("#yourinput").on("input", function(){
    //validation
});
```

or this, to call the validate() function

```
$("#yourinput").on("input", validate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('#FirstName, #LastName, #PhoneNumber, #Email, #Age, #Profession,  #ChooseYourCoursePreferableMonth, #AreYouBringingYourLaptop, #hear, #PreferableContactMethod').keyup(function() {
   validate();
 });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its working!, Here I given  demo of similar code ,please check it : https://jsfiddle.net/cL4wsL3q/2/